# How to prevent Exchange account contacts from hiding local contacts in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, contacts

In Outlook contacts can be read from local PST files or from a MS Exchange server. I want to view my contacts stored in my local PST file. However, once I add an MS Exchange email account to my Outlook profile the local contacts are no longer visible in the contacts tab, only the contacts from the exchange account are visible.

Steps:

1. Import outlook PST file. I can see all of my contacts.
2. Add exchange account to Outlook. Now I only see contacts from the Exchange account on the contacts tab and in the address book search.

It doesn't matter what order I do this in. Is there a work around?

Comment: It's unclear what are you asking. and that basically because your question is hard to read.

Comment: @FranciscoTapia, I updated it, is it clear now?

Comment: In the Address finder ("Select Names") dialog, when you are attached to Exchange, will show the Global Address List (GAL) by default in the dropdown.  Expand the dropdown, and the entry directly above should be "Contacts", which will be your local/personal contacts.  Do your personal contacts show up when you do that?

Answer (score 0):

In Address Book (Select Names) open Tools -> Options. Now you can find that the default setting is "Start with Global Address List". You can reorder address lists as needed by selecting the "Custom" option. You can also choose your local folders to be default address book by choosing in in the dropdown list on the bottom.